# SQL Server Procedure Call

Tags: sql-server

I have this procedure in SQL Server:

```
create procedure SzineszLista
    (@pSzineszNev varchar(30)
     , @pStudiokSzama int
     , @pAtlagKoltseg int
     , @pVetitesSzam int
     , @pOut int output)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if object_id('tempdb..#tmpMufajLista') is not null 
        drop table #tmpMufajLista

    create table #tmpMufajLista(MufajID int)

    if object_id('tempdb..#tmpSzineszLista') is not null 
        drop table #tmpSzineszLista

    create table #tmpSzineszLista
    ( 
         SzineszID int,
         StudiokSzama int,
         AtlagKoltseg int,
         VetitesSzam int
    )

    insert into #tmpMufajLista(MufajID)
        select
            m.MufajID
        from
            Szineszek sz
        inner join 
            szerepel szf on szf.SzineszID = sz.SzineszID
        inner join 
            Filmek f on f.FilmID = szf.FilmID
        inner join 
            MufajID m on m.MufajID = f.MufajID
        where
            sz.SzineszNev = @pSzineszNev
        group by
            m.MufajID

    insert into #tmpSzineszLista(SzineszID, StudiokSzama, AtlagKoltseg, VetitesSzam)
        select
            szf.SzineszID, 0, 0, 0
        from
            #tmpMufajLista tmp
        inner join 
            Filmek f on f.MufajID = tmp.MufajID
        inner join 
            Szerepel szf on szf.FilmID = f.FilmID
        group by
            szf.SzineszID

    update tmp
    set StudiokSzama = sq.StudioSzam
    from #tmpSzineszLista tmp
    inner join (select szl.SzineszID, count(distinct f.StudioID) StudioSzam
                from #tmpSzineszLista szl
                inner join Szerepel szf on szf.SzineszID = szl.SzineszID
                inner join Filmek f on f.FilmID = szf.FilmID
                group by szf.SzineszID) sq on sq.SzineszID = tmp.SzineszID

    update tmp
    set AtlagKoltseg = sq.SzineszAtlagKoltseg
    from #tmpSzineszLista tmp
    inner join (select szl.SzineszID, avg(f.Koltseg) SzineszAtlagKoltseg
                from Filmek f
                cross join #tmpSzineszLista szl
                left outer join Szerepel szf on szf.FilmID = f.FilmID and szf.SzineszID = szl.SzineszID
                where szf.FilmID is null
                group by szl.SzineszID) sq on sq.SzineszID = tmp.SzineszID

    update tmp
    set VetitesSzam = sq2.SzineszVetitesSzam
    from #tmpSzineszLista tmp
    inner join (select szl.SzineszID, count(*) SzineszVetitesSzam
                from
                    (select 
                         szl.SzineszID, f.FilmID,  
                         dense_rank() over (partition by szl.SzineszID, f.FilmID order by f.Koltseg asc) OrderNo
                     from #tmpSzineszLista szl
                     inner join Szerepel szf on szf.SzineszID = szl.SzineszID
                     inner join Filmek f on f.FilmID = szf.FilmID) sq
                inner join Vetites v on v.FilmID = sq.FilmID
                where sq.OrderNo = 1
                group by szl.SzineszID) sq2 on sq2.SzineszID = tmp.SzineszID

    if exists(
        select szl.SzineszID
        from #tmpSzineszLista szl
        where
            szl.StudioSzam < @pStudiokSzama
            and szl.AltagKoltseg < @pAtlagKoltseg
            and szl.VetitesSzam > @pVetitesSzam
        )
    begin
        select sz.SzineszID, sz.SzineszNev
        from #tmpSzineszLista szl
            inner join Szineszek sz on sz.SzineszID = szl.SzineszID
        where
            szl.StudioSzam < @pStudiokSzama
            and szl.AltagKoltseg < @pAtlagKoltseg
            and szl.VetitesSzam > @pVetitesSzam

        set @pOut = 0
    end else begin
        set @pOut = -2
    end
end
```

When I run this code, it's ok, but when I call it, it gives me an error message

```
exec SzineszLista 'Kipp Maeer', 0, 0, 0
```

Error message:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure SzineszLista, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 177]
>   Procedure or function 'SzineszLista' expects parameter '@pOut', which was not supplied.

And if I set a value to @pOut like this:

```
exec SzineszLista 'Kipp Maeer', 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Then the error message is:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SzineszLista, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 177]
>   Invalid object name 'MufajID'.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? It seems that you're trying to delete a row that is being referenced by a row in another table as a foreign key.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Is that the entirery of the code you're running? The fact that you don't operate on any live tables and the fact that the line number indicates is 297 makes me think there's something else

Comment: I agree with Xedni.  Tell us more about [tmp].  Does it have a TRIGGER?

Comment: No, it doesnt have any other parts.@DavidDubois

Comment: Take the header off the procedure so it's essentially a script (and just turn the parameters into regular old delcared variables). Then run it piece by piece until you hit the section throwing the exception.

Comment: Sorry, I putted the wrong error message, but it is updated now.

Comment: The first error, you didn't set the non-nullable output variable. The second error, you're referencing a table which doesn't exist. Look through your code for `MufajID` and see if you're using it wrong./

Comment: do you actually have a table named "MufajId"?
you are using it in the first insert
    inner join 
            MufajID m on m.MufajID = f.MufajID

Answer (score 0):

MufajID is a column, not a table:

```
inner join 
    MufajID m on m.MufajID = f.MufajID
```

Comment: Now I have another error message:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SzineszLista, Line 46 [Batch Start Line 177]
Column '#tmpSzineszLista.SzineszID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That error is self explanatory. Please look up how `group by` works.

Comment: @Xedni I just realised that your comment precedes my answer, if you add your comment as an answer I'll vote it up.